# Lookup Field/table in vb.net (similar to Access)

Tags: vb.net, field, lookup, ms-access-2013

I am working on a Windows Form application in vb.net.   I am wondering if there is a way to setup a lookup field similar to the way you can in MS Access.

For example, you have a Customer table with all of the customer info, and then an Orders table.   The Orders table contains the field CustID, and when someone enters an existing CustID into an Order, I would like to pull in the Customer information into some read-only fields for display.   I can do this with code and SQL statements, but I am wondering if there is an 'automatic' way to do this like there was in the Access world.   Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to write code, and it allows you more freedom than an out-of-the-box solution, but I think you might be looking for [Walkthrough: Creating a Master/Detail Form Using Two Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8c0cxey(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, it is more than possible.